# PHP: compare 2 arrays and create new one

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays, for example the following:

```
$array1 = array(3,4,3,1);

$array2 = array(2,5,3,0);
```

each key of the 2 arrays should now be compared and with the smaller value number of each key,  I want to create a new array. In this case the new array should be this:

```
$result = array(2,4,3,0)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You can do this with a simple for-loop, checking both arrays in parallel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) like this:

```
$array1 = array(3,4,3,1);    
$array2 = array(2,5,3,0);

$result = array_map(min, $array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
```

`array_map` applies a function (in this case [`min`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.min.php)) to each element of an array and returns the resulting array. If more than one array is passed to `array_map`, the corresponding elements from each array are used as arguments to the function.

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 4 [2] => 3 [3] => 0 )
```

Answer (score 2):

[array_map](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) is your friend:

```
$array1 = array(3,4,3,1);
$array2 = array(2,5,3,0);

$array3 = array_map(min,$array1,$array2);

print_r($array3);
```

gives:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as a concept

```
$array3 = array(); 
for($a = 0; a < count($array1); $a++)
{
    if($array1[$a]<$array2[$a])
        $array3[$a]=$array1[$a];
    else
        $array3[$a]=$array2[$a];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if array_push is the most elegant solution, but the result seems to be what you're looking for.

```
$array1 = array(3,4,3,1);
$array2 = array(2,5,3,0);
$result = array();
$len = count($array1);

for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
    $array1[$i] < $array2[$i] ? array_push($result, $array1[$i]) : array_push($result,            $array2[$i]);
}
print_r($result);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 0
)
```